# How to "Group By" by result and count in Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to group some results I have in app insights and am struggling

If I were to tabulate my results, it would look like

```
Product        Version

 A              1
 B              2
 A              2
 A              1
 B              3
 B              3
```

As you can see, I have 2 products (A and B), and each has a version number.

I am trying to group these and provide a count, so my end result is

```
Product        Version       Count

 A              1              2
 A              2              1 
 B              2              1
 B              3              2
```

At the moment, my approach is a mess because I am doing this manually with

```
customEvents
| summarise A1 = count(customEvents.['payload.prod'] == "A" and myEvents.['payload.vers'] == "1"),
| summarise A2 = count(customEvents.['payload.prod'] == "A" and myEvents.['payload.vers'] == "2")
```

I have no idea how I can aggregate these so it can group by product and version and then count the occurrences of each

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think your are looking for:

```
customEvents
| extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.prod) 
| extend MajorVersion = split(customDimensions.Version, ".")[0] 
| summarize Count = count() by Product , tostring(MajorVersion)
```

I wrote this off the top off my head so there might be some syntax issues. I assumed prod and vers are in the customdimensions, let me know if it is otherwise.

You can summarize by multiple fields as you can see.

Comment: This is great. Silly question, does this support split? I hadn't realised until I tried your solution but I'm only after the grouping by major version (and my example only had 1 number for the version). What I actually have is 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 and 2.1.1 etc... Is it possible to also sum by major (which is the first number before the first dot)

Comment: Yes you can. Am on mobile now so can't work out example right now.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions added the split example. split gives you a zero based array